# Segmentizing MultiLineString by distance using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, segment

I want to segmentize a MultiLineString layer by a given maximum distance. Result shall be parts of the input linestring with this maximum length. I am using QGIS 3.16 and want a pure PyQGIS solution.

*Note: It took a while to research and I could not find a question or answer for PyQGIS, so this is written as self-answer question, therefore no codeattempt. But of course, please add your solution!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate over the parts of the MultiLines and use [`QgsLineString.curveSubstring()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.16/core/QgsLineString.html#qgis.core.QgsLineString.curveSubstring) to create the segments. To know the number of segments as well as start- and endpoints of the segments you only need some simple math:

```py
import math
linelayer = iface.activeLayer()
distance = 1000

vl = QgsVectorLayer("LineString?crs={}".format(linelayer.crs().authid()), "temp", "memory")
vl.startEditing()

for line in linelayer.getFeatures():
    linegeom = line.geometry()
    for linepart in linegeom.parts():
        linepartgeom = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(linepart)
        partlength = linepartgeom.length()
        nsegments = math.ceil(partlength / distance)
        startdist = 0
        enddist = distance
        for segment in range(0,nsegments):
            segmentlinestring = linepart.curveSubstring(startdist,enddist)
            segmentgeom = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(segmentlinestring)
            startdist += distance
            enddist += distance
            # Do something with that segment #
            
            f = QgsFeature()
            f.setGeometry(segmentgeom)
            vl.dataProvider().addFeature(f)
vl.updateExtents()
vl.commitChanges()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```